# I am being redirected to IIS7

Tags: wireless-networking, redirection, iis-7

I work for a national builder and someone in my sales department is having an issue with being redirected to IIS7 when opening one of our marketing programs.

We have a **direct link** to it on our company *homepage* and it opens up without problem when connected to the *wifi* in our sales office.

However, when she connects to *another wifi* network at home or a mobile hotspot she keeps being redirected to the IIS7 page and our IT department cannot figure out a solution to this.

Comment: It's possible that the direct link points to an internal name or internal IP address, so only when she's on the local network it works.

Comment: It seems as though you have a problem with port forwarding in your internet router. Check (1) the web server has a fixed IP address on your intranet; (2) port 80 _and any other port the software may use_ is being forwarded there on the same port number(s); and (3) the web server has no firewall rules preventing access to these ports from public networks. Resolution will need some form of network monitoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'd check the DNS entries for the external records, they should be your external IP. Second I'd check the NAT rules on the firewall to ensure they go to the correct device. Third I'd check the DNS names that the IIS site is setup to use.